# Draw on HTML5 canvas using TypeScript (Aurelia)

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas, aurelia

I want to draw on a HTML5 canvas using TypeScript (Aurelia), but can't figure out how to do this.

I have declared a canvas in my html-file:

```
<canvas id="clock" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

How to access this, and draw some shape on it, from my .ts-file?
Please advice, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `ref` to it. This will tell Aurelia to set this element as a property on your View Model (.ts file).

```
 <canvas id="clock" ref="clock" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

in your viewmodel

```
 export class MyViewModel {
   public clock: HTMLCanvasElement;

   attached() {
     const context = this.clock.getContext('2d');

     // now you can do stuff with it
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

for any aurelia custom-element you can inject Element in constructor and have a reference to that in the view..

you can also use the `ref` binding to get your canvas element into vm
http://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#referencing-elements

and for canvas itself go to mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage